# How to use find command to copy .toml files preserving directory structure in Docker?

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, find, exec

I am trying to build a Docker image that copies all the `.toml` files from a specific directory on the host machine into the Docker image while preserving the directory structure. I want to achieve this by using the `find` command with the `exec` option.

Here is the directory structure on the host machine:

```
/host/path/to/toml/files
    ├── subdirectory1
    │   ├── file1.toml
    │   └── file2.toml
    ├── subdirectory2
    │   ├── file3.toml
    │   └── file4.toml
    └── subdirectory3
        └── file5.toml
```

Expected Directory Structure in Docker Container:

```
/app
    ├── subdirectory1
    │   ├── file1.toml
    │   └── file2.toml
    ├── subdirectory2
    │   ├── file3.toml
    │   └── file4.toml
    └── subdirectory3
        └── file5.toml
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM <base_image>

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Create a temporary directory in the container
RUN mkdir /temp

# Copy .toml files from host to temporary directory
RUN find /host/path/to/toml/files -type f -name '*.toml' -exec cp --parents {} /app/ \;

# Remove the temporary directory
RUN rm -rf /temp

# Set entry point or CMD if needed
```

But when I build the Docker image, it fails with an error message.

I suspect that the issue is with the `find` command or the directory paths. How can I modify my Dockerfile or the `find` command to copy the `.toml` files with their respective directory structure intact?

Comment: `RUN` happens in the image, not on the host.

Comment: You also can't `COPY` from an arbitrary host directory; the left-hand side of `COPY` is always relative to the build-context directory.  What's special about these specific TOML files?  Can you rearrange your source tree so you can just `COPY` in the tree of configuration?

Comment: I wanted to learn how to filer and exclude certain directories from the Dockerfile. The python program I wrote uses certain directories that contain TOML files hence why I wanted to only copy them. I could just copy the tree configuration but I wanted to add special filters to it for learning and customizability sake.